# How i split the string with multiple delimeter in scala?

Tags: scala

If I have a string like `"(TIde Pods) OR (Pods) AND (myPods)"` than how its split as `TIde Pods,Pods,myPods`?

```
scala>val s = "Tide POds OR Pods AND (abc ggk)"
s: String = Tide POds OR Pods AND (abc ggk)

scala>s.split("[( ) OR AND]")
res14: Array[String] = Array(Tide, P, ds, "", "", "", Pods, "", "", "", "", "", abc, ggk)
```

I want `Tide Array(POds,Pods,abc ggk)`.

Comment: Can you include more examples for input and desired output?

Answer (score 10):

Since .split accepts [regular expression's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) patterns you can use the following:

```
scala> val str = "(TIde Pods) OR (Pods) AND (myPods)"
str: String = (TIde Pods) OR (Pods) AND (myPods)


scala> str.split("[()\\s]|OR|AND").filter(_.nonEmpty)
res2: Array[String] = Array(TIde, Pods, Pods, myPods)
```